# How to create curriculum presentation for a course with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, siblings

I would like to create a curriculum presentation by Java Script similar to the one on Udemy.

https://prnt.sc/22zxxrp

I have tried to put both button and content in the same div and to add an event listener which would on click trigger conditional check if both of the elements are of the same parent and if true to display the content.

But it does not work.

The code would be something like this but with more buttons.

```
   let batonceros  = document.getElementsByClassName("batno");

   let paragraph = document.getElementsByClassName("para");



   batonceros.addEventListener("click", function() {

   if( batonceros != paragraph && batonceros.parentNode == paragraph.parentNode) {
    
    batonceros.style.display = "block";
}

else {
    batonceros.style.display = "none";
    
  }
 });
```

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) always returns a HTMLCollection.  You can't treat it like an element.

Comment: I guess you mean I can not treat it like a single element, right? Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe this might help. It shows how to reference the parent container to find the relative `.para` from its `.batno`

```js
let batonceros = document.querySelectorAll(".batno");
let paragraph = document.querySelectorAll(".para");

batonceros.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.closest('div').querySelector('.para').classList.toggle('show');
}));
```

```css
.para {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class='para'>This is a paragraph</p>
  <button class='batno'>Button</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p class='para'>This is a paragraph</p>
  <button class='batno'>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to accomplish exactly what you have done. Thank you. If I understand well this  " e.target.closest('div').querySelector('.para').classList.toggle('show');" we add/remove class "show" to the element within the closest div of the button or its parent element, which has the element with class ".para"? Is this the logic?

Comment: @Lucky - yes, that is right. `closest(".div")` finds the matching containing `div` element, then `querySelector(".para")` finds the first instance of the matching `class="para"` element inside that container.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, try to see if it works without checking the parent.  Also, no need to check to see if the button equals the paragraph.  Also, you are changing the button style, not the paragraph style.

```js
batonceros.addEventListener("click", function() {  
    paragraph.style.display = "block";
}
```

If this does cause the paragraph to display, your problem may in your element structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried it and it throws an error - batonceros.addEventListener is not a function. I will look at it a bit more.